# Apache - how to get REMOTE_USER variable

Tags: apache, fastcgi

Previously I used the IIS server as PHP server. Currently, it is the apache.

On IIS I could access to the variable `$_SERVER ['REMOTE_USER']` which returns the username and domain (eg domain\user) but after installing XAMPP this variable is not available.

What I should do to get this variable get again?

My app is on local network with no-internet connection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally got it to works! :D

1. Download the module from here https://www.apachehaus.net/modules/mod_authnz_sspi/  (x86 for 32 bit and x64 for 64 bit apache)
2. Copy the mod_authnz_sspi.so from `Apache24\modules` folder and place it in the modules folder of your Apache folder on your webserver
3. Under the httpd.conf file (Config file for your apache) place this line of code. Try to load this as the last module:

   `LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so`
4. Make sure that the following modules are uncommented

   `LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so`

   `LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so`

   PS: both the above modules are required for this to work.
5. Place the following code in your httpd.conf file

   > ```
   > <Directory "path/to/your/htcdocs/folder"> 
   > Options None 
   > AllowOverride All 
   > Order allow,deny 
   > Allow from all 
   > #AuthName "SSPI Protected Place" 
   > AuthType SSPI 
   > SSPIAuth On 
   > SSPIAuthoritative On 
   > SSPIOfferBasic On 
   > SSPIOmitDomain On 
   > Require valid-user 
   > </Directory>
   > ```
6. Restart your apache servive and hopefully it should restart without any issues.
7. Now in order to recognise the user , use the following code on a php page

   > echo $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];

That's all.

I'm using:

- XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.1
- APACHE 2.4

Comment: Has anyone compared this to the new [mod_authn_ntlm](https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=25073) module? mod_authnz_sspi and mod_authn_ntlm both seem to have been released around the same time. Any differences?

Comment: Since 2023, apachehaus.net is closed. I found no direct download forthe apache 2.4 version, and got mine from the 'GLPI project'

Answer (score 2):

```
<Directory "path/to/your/htcdocs/folder"> 
Options None 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
#AuthName "SSPI Protected Place" 
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic On 
SSPIOmitDomain On 
Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

If you use ModRewrite or other I suggest you to keep

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
```

otherwise you'll get an error like

```
[rewrite:error]: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only access the remote user if Apache has actually authenticated the user, check [the apache auth howto](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html).

Answer (score 0):

I battled with this for a long time, it turned out that I had to install VC redistributable to make it work.

Comment: should the machine running xampp be registered to the domain?