# Apache on Linux - how to get remote user login

Tags: linux, apache

Few days ago I was [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994329/apache-how-get-remote-user-variable) about getting `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` as apache.
After few hours I have found a module for apache which allows me to get `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` variable which is similiar to `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']` on windows IIS service.

Now I have to move my apps from windows/xampp server to linux (probably some kind of debian distro - don't know it yet).
And my questions is:

1. Is it possible to get remote username on linux? (users are login into domain, site works only on local intranet with no internet access)
2. Does this module also works on linux-apache or it is only for windows?
3. Is there any similiar module which allows me to get aforementioned variable?

Comment: How are logins performed? Using an apache authentication module or something else?

Comment: User logs on to the computer to the domain. Next apache should get him login. I can't explain it simpler

Comment: So users are logged in a domain controller (presumably Microsoft AD or something which pretends to be one) and you want to have some kind of a single sign-on chained to Apache which should not ask the user to authenticate him/her/itself another time? You really should put some more details into your question and mention also what you're actually trying to accomplish, not just the way you think you might get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer there is mod_auth_gssapi which can be used for remote authentication with Windows.It also supplies the mentioned REMOTE_USER variable. You can find a link to the Github repo here:
[Github](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi)