# IE domain autologin php

Tags: php, internet-explorer, sharepoint

So I noticed with SharePoint sites if you are using IE, it automatically sends your AD username/pass to the server. Now I'm being asked if the same can be done with the other internal websites. The other websites are written in php and I don't have access to the server settings, just to the php scripts. I did find a way to authenticate against AD from php scripts once the username and password gets submitted to the scripts. So I'm like halfway there once the script knows what user/pass, the user wants to use it can check if it's valid. but what I still need to know is how to tell IE that this page needs to know the user/pass they are logged in as like the SharePoint site pages can.

Comment: Are the other websites being run as web applications under IIS or some other web server software (such as Apache)? You're not the first to run into [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070058/ntlm-authentication-get-windows-login-domain-and-host-in-php)

Comment: the server I have access to is using apache, I don't got any access to the iis one that the sharepoint stuff is on.

Comment: Check out [Tim Clutton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070058/ntlm-authentication-get-windows-login-domain-and-host-in-php#30256118) on that question I linked in my previous comment, since that seems to be an Apache-specific solution. Good luck!