# How can I get the logged in username?

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache

Im working on a page, that contains, the modifications of a database ( have a webpage, where you can modify the database and this is a history database of the modifications which contains when, what have been modified). On this page/ in this database I have to store that who modified it. 
And my quetion is that how can I get the windows user name. 
Im working on apache server mysql db and in php and i have to get only windows users.

Comment: where is you code?

Comment: Paste your code first

Comment: Normal webpage or company intranet? In other words is there an active directory you could use?

Comment: I think we have active directory.

Comment: If you have active directory then you should be able to use ldap queries to get whatever information you want from AD

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070058/ntlm-authentication-get-windows-login-domain-and-host-in-php

Comment: I dont really have code about this, I tried sg, but it doesnt really work

Comment: Thanks some1, I'll check it.

Comment: I didnt really config mod_auth_sspi, but in th httpd.conf file I found a mod_authz_user without #. It should show me $_Server["PHP_AUTH_USER"] or sgh like this?

Comment: It depends at a minimum on how PHP and Apache are configured, and what sort of authentication you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on my laptop:

```
cmd> php -r "exec('echo %username%', $output); var_dump($output);"
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(7) "jigar.d"
}
```

And if you want username along with computer name:

```
cmd> php -r "exec('echo %username%@%computername%', $output); var_dump($output);"
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(20) "jigar.d@****JIGARD"
}
```

Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

For authentication of intranet PHP based applications we use [PHP LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) to connect and authenticate users.

**Note:** My laptop is on AD as well. I have `*` my actual `computername`.

Comment: Thanks its do sgh, but im sure that it isnt my user name what it gaves back. I think its maybe the name of the virtual server were it runs.