# Getting name of logged in Windows user via Php on Apache

Tags: php, apache

I cannot seem to get the Windows username of the logged in user via Php / Apache.

I have downloaded and added this module in Apache:

```
LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so
```

But when I call this from PHP via:

```
print $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] ;
```

I still get: Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_USER. Please note this is an intranet site so running on an internal LAN. The server hosting the site is XAMPP.

I have also tried this: [Apache - how to get REMOTE_USER variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994329/apache-how-to-get-remote-user-variable) but I am getting a prompt to re-enter my username and password (using Chrome and IE) something which I do not want. I also added this to my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs"> 
Options None 
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
#AuthName "SSPI Protected Place" 
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIOfferBasic On 
SSPIOmitDomain On 
Require valid-user 
</Directory>
```

Comment: I don't know if this will be of any use but there is some useful looking info here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994329/apache-how-to-get-remote-user-variable

Comment: question has been edited to clarify further